How to access QInput element on mounted in Quasar 2
I want to access QInput element on mounted, so I make a custom directive. When I logged to the console, the element shown is QLabel. How to correctly access QInput element when it is mounted?
<template>
  <q-page padding>
    <q-input v-selectall clearable label="Please enter your message here" />
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, computed } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'IndexPage',
  directives: {
    selectall: {
      mounted(el, bind, a) {
        console.log('input was mounted', el, bind, a) // el is QLabel, not QInput
        el.select() // it's not working because the element here is a label element
      }
    }
  },
});
</script>



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Every single Quasar component, usually, is wrapped by several HTML tags. To access the main element (input here), you would get the element by tag name (el.getElementsByTagName) or other query options.
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'IndexPage',
  directives: {
    selectall: {
      mounted(el, bind, a) {
        el.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].select()
      }
    }
  },
});

